# Difference in parameters between grid summary and individual models

Tags: boosting, h2o

I was using h2o for getting a feel of what learning rate does a good job on my data set. I chose to use cross validation for selecting a learning rate.

```
fit.gbm.grid = h2o.gbm(...learn_rate=seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1), nfold=5, ....)
```

When I looked at the summary table of the grid(ordered by increasing deviance(rmse^2)):

```
fit.grid@summary_table %>% data.frame %>% select(learn_rate, residual_deviance)


learn_rate    residual_deviance

1        0.02  0.02523190479495407
2        0.01 0.025250571726902316
3        0.02 0.025250821218483113
4        0.03 0.025259080075877502
5        0.01   0.0252612284475692
6        0.01 0.025263035251822462
7        0.01 0.025263035251822462
8        0.04 0.025269296481300323
9        0.03  0.02526962790624404
10       0.02  0.02527191327680234
```

This suggests that a decent learning rate to start with is 0.01-0.02

I also plotted the individual model's score history, i.e. RMSE vs ntrees grouped by learning rate:

```
getRMSEScoreHistory = function (models) {
    # Given a list of model ids get a data frame with its RMSE score history and the learning rates for the models that created it.
    score.history = data.frame()

    for (i in 1:length(models)) {
        lr = models[[i]]@parameters$learn_rate
        v_rmse= h2o.scoreHistory(models[[i]]) %>%
            data.frame %>%
            pull(validation_rmse)
        t_rmse= h2o.scoreHistory(models[[i]]) %>%
            data.frame %>%
            pull(training_rmse)
        score.history = rbind(score.history,
                              data.frame(
                                         ntrees = 1:length(v_rmse),
                                         validation_rmse = v_rmse,
                                         training_rmse = t_rmse,
                                         id = i,
                                         lr = lr
                                         )
                              )
    }
    score.history
}
```

And plotted the validation RMSE vs ntrees for each learning rate using the following code:

```
models = sapply(FUN=function(m) h2o.getModel(m), fit.grid@model_ids)
score.history.combined = getRMSEScoreHistory(models)

min_y_lim = score.history.combined %>% pull(validation_rmse) %>% min
max_y_lim = score.history.combined %>% pull(validation_rmse) %>% max

ggplot(score.history.combined) +
        facet_wrap(~ lr) + 
        geom_line(aes(y=validation_rmse, x=ntrees, color=as.factor(id))) +
        ylim(c(min_y_lim, max_y_lim)) +
        theme(
          legend.position="NULL",
          strip.background = element_blank()
        )
```

I get:
[image]

The colors represent the different models within each cross validated model.

I also plotted the training_rmse and got:

[image]

Which indicates that the higher learning rate is achieving a *lower* RMSE, which is at odds with the summary table.

So how is the summary table calculated from the individual models? And why is it different from the individual models' scoring history?

PS: I had a large number of trees and early stopping enabled at a tree depth of 10.

Cluster Info:

```
> h2o.clusterInfo()
R is connected to the H2O cluster:
H2O cluster uptime:         1 days 50 minutes
H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.18.0.5
H2O cluster version age:    8 days
H2O cluster name:           H20Demo
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster total memory:   2.42 GB
H2O cluster total cores:    8
H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
H2O Connection ip:          localhost
H2O Connection port:        54321
H2O Connection proxy:       NA
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
R Version:                  R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
```

Comment: Can you say something about your data? How many records, and is it unbalanced? Also, was `h2o.gbm(...)` a typo for `h2o.grid('gbm',...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

> This suggests that a decent learning rate to start with is 0.01-0.02

My reading of your summary table was that `learn_rate` is *not* influencing performance:

- Your best model and your worst model both used a learn rate of 0.02. (*)
- The best was 0.02523, the worst was 0.02527. I.e the whole range was 0.00004.

(*: worst of the 10 you show - I think you made 20 models altogether?)

Instead, what struck me from your charts was that for each learning rate you have 4 models, and in each case one of the models:

- is learning notably worse
- uses more trees

The first point suggests another of your grid parameters (not `learn_rate`) is having the most effect: 3 of the values are roughly equivalent, but the 4th one is bad. Colour-coding by another grid parameter, rather than model id, might bring that out more clearly?

The second point is strange: early stopping shouldn't have stopped the other 3 lines each time, because they all look like they are still improving, even on the validation data. Without seeing the full code (and ideally a fully reproducible example) I cannot really say why that might be.

P.S. I love the example of using ggplot to study the H2O model data.

Comment: Thats a good observation about another parameter making one of the models do worst than the other, let me go back and have a look at the grid if something pops out. Thanks!

Comment: >"The best was 0.02523, the worst was 0.02527. I.e the whole range was 0.00004. "
The table says so yes, but the pictures show models with learning rates like 0.04 and 0.05 do better than 0.02/0.01. I am thinking that from an h2o point of view how are the individual models combined to get the summary table exactly?

Comment: @Sid It might be helpful to have the plots show deviance (or have the table show rmse), and show all 20 models from the summary, to make it clearer if they are showing the same data or not.